# Display value emitted from Vue component

Tags: vue.js, components, render, display, emit

I created two separated Vue components and I able to emit a message thru a bus.

How can I render/display the message in the component that receives the message.

Example of the Vue component that receives the message:

```
<template>
    <div v-model="cars">
        Car model: {{ model }}

        <input type="button" @click="display" value="example" />
    </div>

</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cars: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            bus.$on('CARS_LOADED', (cars) => {
                this.cars = cars;
            });
        },
        methods: {
            display()
            {
                console.log(this.cars);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can successfully emit and received the message, however the car model is not updated. I checked the message received and it contains the "model" key with a right value.

I cannot see any error in the Vue console and however if I replace "{{ model }}" by "{{ cars }}" I can see the full message object updated.

I am using Vue 2.x.

Update:
I enclose an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kvzvxk4f/1/

As you can see in the example I cannot render an specific field from the object, however I can render the object as string.

Comment: Could you share the component where you emit the value? Just to check, do you import the bus at some point in your components?

Comment: what do you expect `v-model="cars"` to do when attached to a `<div>`?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are misunderstanding some parts of the vue syntax.

**How to access properties of an object:**

You just need to write  `{{ car.model }}` to access a property of an object.

**How to iterate through an array in a template:**

If you want to display all the `cars` in your template, you should write:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
    {{ car }}
</div>
```

As you see, the `v-for` directive allows you to iterate through an array.

**What is `v-model`?**

`v-model` is used to bind a variable to an input or a component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="foo" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In that case, the `foo` property will be bound to the input text.

**Last point:**

In your case, to make it work, you also need to create a root element for your template, because a template can't have multiple root elements:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="car in cars">
            {{ car }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The message sent is an object not array. the object structure is something like {name:"Mercedes", model:"Benz"}.

Comment: Ho, ok I edited my response, see "how to access the property of an object"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I just have to type property separated by ".". Like for example {{cars.model}}.

```
<template id="compo2">
  <div>
    <div>
       {{ field.name }}
    </div>
    <div>
      Received: {{ field }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zuhb7s8q/3/